# How to solve this Equation?? 55

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

How do I solve this differential equation in terms of s1 and s2?

[image: How do I solve this equation?]

```
DSolve[(D[Q[x, y], x, y]*a*(x - y)^2) - (a*x*D[Q[x, y], x]) - (a*y*D[Q[x, y], y]) - (b*x*Q[x, y]) - (b*y*Q[x, y]) == 0, 
 Q[x, y], {x, y}]
```

where a=mu, b=nu

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: your syntax is fine, most likely there is no general analytic solution.